# obtener el barrio desde una dirección domiciliaria, vb.net

Tags: vb.net

necesito identificar las direcciones de una ciudad y así obtener el barrio en el cual se encuentra. Estoy investigando sobre Gmap.Net pero no tiene nada de ello, y no encuentro como lograr dicho cometido!, es sencillo pero no se como podría lograrse, con tantos mapas que se encuentran gratuitos en la red. 
Aqui una idea sencilla para aclarar la pregunta, tengo la siguiente funcion

```
Function obtenerbarrio(direccion As String) As String
'sentencia para procesar dicha direccion
return direccionalaquepertenecedireccionespecificada
end function
```

Luego de una investigación he verificado que existe la base de datos GeoNames, de los cuales se puede averiguar muchos datos a partir de la latitude y longitud también se puede obtener el barrio. Estas (Latitud y longitud) se puede obtener a través de una consulta en googlemaps desde una dirección especificadas, así que la idea la desarrolle en dos partes, la primero a partir desde una dirección, con Google maps Api, me entrega la latitud y longitud (coordenadas), de los cuales ya lo tengo hecho, el problema que se me presenta ahora es pasar la longitud y latitud a geonames y obtener el barrio. Geonames, es gratuito. te da la posibilidad de realizar consultas si te creas un usuario. Estas consultas para llevarlas a cabo desde una aplicación .NET es necesario una extensión, que es la NGEO2, de las cuales se encuentra en esta dirección "https://github.com/Obalix/NGeo2".
En el ejemplo que dan, la consulta con esta extension es realizada de la siguiente manera en C#:

```
// needs only to be performed once, alternatively you can specify the user name with each request.
NGeoSettings.UserName = "username";

var request = new FindNearbyToponymRequest() {
    Latitude = 47.3m,
    Longitude = 9m,
    Style = Style.FULL
};
var response = await GeoNameService.FindNearbyToponym(request);
```

Que no se como hacerlo en VB.NET, así que la pregunta se podría resolver realizando una conversión de este código.
Si alguien me podría ayudar puedo formular una respuesta así cierro el tema con una respuesta simple, Espero su ayuda gracias

Comment: A que llamas "barrio"? No es tan sencillo como te parece, ya que el concepto de barrio es difuso a veces y no creo que existan muchas bases de datos que contemplen ese concepto

Comment: convertir la direccion (STRING) a nombre de barrio al cual pertenece (STRING)

Comment: Tienes que usar la API de google, aqui un ejemplo en javascript: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Comment: Yo estuve investigando geonames, obtener la latitudes y longitud con la base de datos de openmap a través de ngeo2, y desde ese dato obtener el barrio con geonames, que la base de datos se puede subir a mi base de datos MySQL, estoy desarrollando pero son todos con licencia GNU, que es lo que estoy buscando, la api de GooGle me pide pagar dinero